# Getting Checkbox index in Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, checkbox

I have listbox which contains one textblock and another checkbox.
In xaml file it looks something like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="notificationSettingsListBox" Grid.Row="1"   Margin="20,20,20,20" Background="#e79e38" SelectionChanged="notificationSettingsListBox_SelectionChanged" Tap="notificationSettingsListBox_Tap">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="#055cc3" Width="500" Height="200" Margin="30,40,30,20">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding channel_name}" Foreground="White" FontSize="31" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,20,10,0" />
                        <CheckBox Name="pushNotiOnCheckBox" Content="Enable Notification" IsChecked="false" Foreground="White" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" Checked="pushNotiOnCheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="pushNotiOnCheckBox_Unchecked"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Now whenever user checks any checkbox i need the index of the checkbox.
I want the index from the inside of this method:

```
private void pushNotiOnCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {}
```

How can I achieve that in Windows phone?

Comment: What do you have in the `ListBox.ItemsSource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have `List<T>` in the `ListBox.ItemsSource`, then you can use [`IndexOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get the index of the underlying model in the `ItemsSource`, which corresponds to the index of the `CheckBox` in the `ListBox` :

```
private void pushNotiOnCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //get the checkbox that corresponds to current checked event
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
    //get the underlying model object from DataContext
    MyModel model = (MyModel)chk.DataContext;
    //get the entire models used to populate the ListBox
    var models = (List<MyModel>)notificationSettingsListBox.ItemsSource;
    //find index of current model in the models list,
    //which should be the same as checkbox index you want
    var index = models.IndexOf(model);
}
```

Comment: One problem arises that is when i check the checkbox it doesn't show the check mark . Why does it happen ?? @har07

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `ItemContainer` Style.

```
<ListBox SelectedIndex={Binding Index,Mode=Twoway}>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                            Value="{Binding IsOperationSelected,Mode=TwoWay}" />
           </Style>
      </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

And in you need to change your `CheckBox.IsChecked` to Binding Like this

```
<CheckBox Name="pushNotiOnCheckBox" Content="Enable Notification" IsChecked="{Binding IsOperationSelected,Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="White" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" Checked="pushNotiOnCheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="pushNotiOnCheckBox_Unchecked"/>
```

Comment: But how can i get the index into the Checked or Unchecked method

Comment: @imon why you need the index in the first place? Do you intend to get the corresponding item from the listbox itemssource by using the index?

Comment: Now whenever user checks any checkbox i need the corresponding index of the checkbox. @har07

Comment: @imon Assume you found a way to get it, what do you plan to do with that index?

Comment: I just print the index of the checkbox. @har07